# Execution failed for task ':react-native-multi-image-selector:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' in react native

Tags: react-native

I am just install [react-native-multi-image-selector](/questions/tagged/react-native-multi-image-selector)
and execute the link command, after am trying to build assembleDebug app

It shows an error

```
\node_modules\react-native-multi-image-selector\android\src\main\java\me\nereo\multi_image_selector\MultiImagePackage.java:17: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
 ^

   
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
:react-native-multi-image-selector:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-multi-image-selector:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I don't know how to overcome from this, am very new to react-native

How can I solve this?